# Change the image style af an AppBarCommand in winJs

Tags: windows-8, winjs, windows-8.1, navbar, appbar

I've seen the new navbar control in winJs 2.0 for windows 8.1, is fantastic an simple.

But how did they develop the weather app navbar in windows 8? I mean the nice big squared buttons instead of the small round ones?

The only way I found is to have an appbar and don't use any AppBarCommands (because I can't find a way to change the shape of those) but only divs and do all the styling manually.

Is that the only solution or is it possible to square the circle?

Comment: Have you tried to change the `border-radius` of the buttons to `0`?

Comment: it does actually work if I change every class around it from the dom explorer. can you help me find out which one is exactly the class that I have to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it myself in the end, changing those classes can change entirely the style of the AppBarCommand:

```
CSS class           Description
win-command         Styles the entire AppBarCommand.
win-commandicon     Styles the icon box for the AppBarCommand.
win-commandimage    Styles the image for the AppBarCommand.
win-commandring     Styles the icon ring for the AppBarCommand.
win-label           Styles the label for the AppBarCommand.
```

for example to square the circle:

```
.win-appbar .win-commandring
{
    border-radius: 0;
}

.win-appbar:hover .win-commandring
{
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

It's a hard job to ovverride all the default behaviour but it can be done.

Have a look at this for an example of the main styles: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj839733.aspx